# Should I re-send my app optimized to iOS5? (it was sent last sunday / iOS4)

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I **sent an app to iTunes Connect last sunday**, optimized to **iOS4** (also works in iOS5 beta 7).

Today Apple released iOS5 Gold Master version.

**Should I re-send my app to iTunes Connect compiled to iOS5?**, or they will approve my app, and (next week, for example),  I could re-send it.

Thank u ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know what you mean by “optimizing” your app for iOS 4. (Deployment target?) But in either case I don’t think you have to resubmit the app, AFAIK there is nothing to be gained by simply recompiling with a new SDK version.

Comment: I should say "compile with XCode 4.1". Thx!